# detecting characters in strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I´m geting a string by serial port, I´m using

`readport(linker).startswith('STUFF')`

this method works if there is just one line but when it comes several lines works only with the first line readed contains that word,  the message that im getting, i.e:

STUFF1 ...

STUFF2 ...

STUFF3 ...

STUFF4 ...

if i use `readport(linker).startswith('STUFF4')` it returns false, but if i put STUFF1 works...

its supose to be diferent lines in there or im missing something.

the code is something like this

```
while state == 2:

    print state

    time.sleep(0.1) 

    if readport(linker).startswith('STUFF4') == True:

        results.append(readport(linker).rstrip())
        state = 3
        print results

    else:
        print results
        line = readport(linker).rstrip()
        results.append(line)
        state = 2
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that `linker` can be multiple lines. You ultimately don't know if it will or it will not be multiple lines? So sometimes linker will just be a single line, and other times it will be "X" lines?

Comment: thats it @idjaw somethimes can be 1 and others X

Comment: Is there a delimiter in these messages you can use to split on? How do you know what is considered a full "line"? Even if it is just one, there should be something that ends that line?

Comment: every line ends with \r\n

Comment: OK. Then all you should have to do is iterate over `linker.split('\r\n')` -> `for line in linker.split('\r\n'):`. Inside that loop each `line` will be what you want to do your `startswith` check.

Comment: thanks @idjaw it worked,